# If 2 or more row-values are identical, change these values but 1 to np.nan except for the identical values equal to 0

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I'm having a dataframe with energy use data. In order to post-process the data I need to be sure I only go forward with reliable energy uses.
One of the steps here is making sure the values in the dataframe rows are not identical, because this indicates an error in the database (energy use for households are hardly ever identical over the years except for zero energy uses (due to renewable energy installations).

The question is as follows on a simple example df:

- The dataframe can contain empty cells (np.nan).
- If 2 or more row-values are identical, then keep one of the
  identical values and set the rest to np.nan except if the identical values are zeros.

In the example below, row 2 and 4 are replaced with np.nan but the last row is not because the identical values are zeros.

Does anyone know how to go from the initial df to the desired df? The code works except for the condition if the identical values are zeros, these should not be changed to np.nan (see last row in df)

**Initial df:**

```
   y_2010  y_2011  y_2012
      4.0     6.0     3.0
      2.0     7.0     7.0
      9.0     NaN     NaN
      3.0     3.0     3.0
      2.0     4.0     6.0
      0.0     0.0     NaN
```

**Desired df:**

```
   y_2010  y_2011  y_2012
      4.0     6.0     3.0
      2.0     7.0     NaN
      9.0     NaN     NaN
      3.0     NaN     NaN
      2.0     4.0     6.0
      0.0     0.0     NaN
```

**Tried code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"y_2010": [4,2,9,3,2,0],
                   "y_2011": [6,7,np.nan,3,4,0],
                   "y_2012": [3,7,np.nan,3,6,np.nan]})
print(df)

mask = df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated, 1)
df = df.mask(mask, np.nan)

print(df)

   y_2010  y_2011  y_2012
      4.0     6.0     3.0
      2.0     7.0     NaN
      9.0     NaN     NaN
      3.0     NaN     NaN
      2.0     4.0     6.0
      0.0     NaN     NaN  -> 0 changed to NaN and I don't want that
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try adding 0 check

```
df = df.mask(df.apply(pd.Series.duplicated, 1) & df.ne(0))
   y_2010  y_2011  y_2012
0     4.0     6.0     3.0
1     2.0     7.0     NaN
2     9.0     NaN     NaN
3     3.0     NaN     NaN
4     2.0     4.0     6.0
5     0.0     0.0     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.mask(x.duplicated()&x.ne(0)), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   y_2010  y_2011  y_2012
0     4.0     6.0     3.0
1     2.0     7.0     NaN
2     9.0     NaN     NaN
3     3.0     NaN     NaN
4     2.0     4.0     6.0
5     0.0     0.0     NaN
```